# Where to find Vuetify material icon list

Tags: vuetify.js

Vuetify official doc says you can use the google material icon but some of them not working in is there is any reference online?

```
  <v-icon >
        mdi-layers
  </v-icon>
```

the above works but  the below one  does't

[From google material icon](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=expand)

```
 <v-icon>
        mdi-expand_more
 </v-icon>
```

Comment: [Material Design Icons](https://icons8.com/icons/material) is also supported. Simply use the ```mdi-``` prefixed icon name. Please note that you still need to include the MDI icons in your project. Even [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2) is supported you just have to add prefix ```fa-```. You can refer this link - [https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/)

Comment: what about google material icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the resources I personally use to **get** **mdi icon names**:

**https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/5.4.55/**

**https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline**

**https://iconify.design/icon-sets/mdi/**

Comment: https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/5.4.55/ have full details of icon, thank you @Ambassel